# Does angular-ui-grid allow for changing the filter on a specific cell?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I've found a lot of good information about the angular-ui-grid cell filters but I can't seem to locate an answer to my specific issue. Basically I have a grid set up with two columns:

Column A is a editable cell dropdown where you can pick two options, 'money' or 'percentage'. Column B is a number input displaying a value.

I have two filters in my app, 'currency' and 'percentage'. If I set up the columnDefs for either of those filters, then Column B will display all the values in that column as either a currency value or percentage.

What I need it to do though is to make it so that the filter is applied to Column B based on the setting of Column A, so I end up with this:

```
Value Type               Value
---------------------------------------
Money                    $100.00
Percentage                100%
```

I've got some code to basically check that after the edit:

```
        $scope.gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function(rowData) {
                var row = _.indexOf($scope.items, rowData);
                if (rowData['valueType'] == 'percentage') {
                    // Apply percentage filter to the value cell for this row
                } else {
                   // Apply currency filter to the value cell for this row
                }
                $scope.gridApi.core.refresh();
        });
```

...I'm just not sure how to apply the filter to the individual cells. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else ever has the same question, I managed this by creating a filter that took the row entity as an argument, then applied the custom filters inside of that new filter based on the entity values.